# Lua sub-dissector for rtcp inside a proprietary protocol

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am new to lua script. I am working on dissecting a proprietary protocol. Inside the protocol bytes there are 8 bytes related to rtcp, like, rtcp version, padding,  reception report count, packet type, length and ssrc. A total of 8 bytes. my question is, how to sub-dissect those bytes inside my proprietary protocol?

Basically I need to use rtcp sub-dissector to present the below:

```
10.. .... = Version: RFC 1889 Version (2)  
..0. .... = Padding: False  
...0 0001 = Reception report count: 1  
Packet type: Report (200)  
Length: 12 (52 bytes)  
SSRC: 0x107bb175 (276541813)
```

I am trying the below code:

```
my_proto = Proto("my_proto",  "My Protocol")  

magic_number = ProtoField.uint32("my_proto.magic_number", "Magic number", base.DEC)  
version     = ProtoField.uint16("my_proto.version"     , "Version"    , base.DEC)  

my_proto.fields = { magic_number, version )  

function my_proto.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)  
  length = buffer:reported_length_remaining()  
  local offset = 0  
  if length < 16 then return end  

    local subtree = tree:add(my_proto, buffer:range(offset,length), "My protocol (Report)")  

    subtree:add(magic_number, buffer(offset,4))  
    offset = offset + 4  
    subtree:add(version,     buffer(offset,2))  
    offset = offset + 2  
    -- Then I have 8 bytes related to rtcp protocol, i.e. version, padding, etc.  
        Dissector.get("rtcp"):call(buffer(offset, offset+8):tvb(), pinfo, subtree)
```

This line:  `Dissector.get("rtcp"):call(buffer(offset, offset+8):tvb(), pinfo, subtree)`
is not working for me. I need it to be presented as below:

```
10.. .... = Version: RFC 1889 Version (2)  
..0. .... = Padding: False  
...0 0001 = Reception report count: 1  
Packet type: Report (200)  
Length: 12 (52 bytes)  
SSRC: 0x107bb175 (276541813)
```

Any help please?

Comment: Try moving the `Dissector.get("rtcp")` call **outside** and above your `my_proto.dissector()` function, e..g, `local rtcp_dissector = Dissector.get("rtcp")`, then use the `rtcp_dissector` inside your dissector function if it's not `nil`.  For an example, see: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html/#wslua_dissector_example

Comment: Thanks it helped. But still I get all fields of rtcp,, like Timestamp, MSW: 0 (0x00000000), Timestamp, LSW: 0 (0x00000000), etc. Any idea on how to dissect only 8 bytes needed (up to ssrc), below is my call to rtcp dissectro:
rtcp_dissector:call(buffer(7):tvb(8), pinfo, subtree)

Comment: Try passing only 8 bytes for the length instead of `offset+8`, e.g., `rtcp_dissector:call(buffer(offset, 8):tvb(), pinfo, subtree)`.

Comment: Thanks again, it parsed required 8 bytes, but dissection stops there and it does not proceed with the original dissection flow (i.e. my_proto.dissector). I get the below in wireshark: "[Packet size limited during capture: RTCP truncated]". Any idea on how to proceed with original dissector?

Comment: Well, the RTCP dissector is obviously expecting more data, which isn't available, so you're always going to get that "truncated" situation.  You could try to dissect everything else, skipping those 8 bytes, and only pass those 8 bytes to the RTCP dissector once you've performed all the other dissection.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I did. But unfortunately, it override cols.info, I need to update it accordingly. An option maybe can help but I am not sure it is possible, is it possible to make a copy of 8 bytes, a copy of packetInfo and a copy of a tree then I can retrieve each field manually that I know how to do. Thanks!

Comment: You could set a column fence so the RTCP dissector doesn't overwrite the info column but rather appends to it.  Ref 11.5.2.6: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html/#lua_class_Column.  Or you could read the Info column and overwrite it again with that same string after RTCP has written to it.

Comment: The issue is that after line of rtco dissector nothing being executed even a simple print. Any suggestion regarding working on a copy of bytes and a copy tree? Then I can retrieve fields needed..

Comment: OK, well if you set the info column fence *before* calling the RTCP dissector, then at least you'll preserve your information in the Info column and the RTCP dissector will only append to it.  As for working with a copy, I'm not sure what you mean exactly.  Note that it might be easier to work through ideas on the [Wireshark Discord Server](https://discord.com/invite/ts9GZCjGj5).  I may not be available but others usually are and might have other ideas for you.  There's a Lua channel that would fit well for this discussion.